# Delimited string regex exclude match inside quotes

Tags: c#, regex

I have strings that contains words enclosed between $ OR $$ symbol. I have to replace such words with some other word provided these delimited words are not surrounded by single quotes.

Example:

Original string:
The *$quick$* brown *'$$fox$$'* jumps *$$over$$* the *'$lazy$'* dog

String after substitution should be:
The **substitute** brown *'$$fox$$'* jumps **substitute** the *'$lazy$'* dog

So far I have come up with the regex

```
\$[^$]+\$|\${2}[^$]+\${2}
```

This matches all the patterns within the string regardless of the single quotes. How can I make it ignore the ones enclosed inside single quotes?

Comment: for ' brown &&fox&& jumps', should fox be subed? or only when ' immediately comes before/after the &&?

Comment: You *can* solve this with regular expressions, but I would argue you shouldn't.

Comment: Are you going to differentiate between `$$...$$` and `$...$` matches? Like replacing them with something else? If not, the task is as simple as match and capture all between single quotes and just match `(?<!\$)(\${1,2})[^$]+\1(?!\$)` to remove it (I am adding the lookarounds to avoid matching `$$$....$$$`). Another question: can there be any escape sequences inside single quotes? Like `'sss \' dddd \\\nhhhh'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use lookaround like this.

**Regex:** `(?<=\s)([$]{1,2})[^\$]*\1(?=\s)`

**Explanation:**

`(?<=\s)` is positive lookbehind for `whitespace` to check if previous character was a whitespace. If `'` is present then it won't match.

`([$]{1,2})[^\$]*\1` matches word between `$` or `$$`.

`([$]{1,2})` catches `$` or `$$` and matches it for second time at end of word using capturing group `\1`.

`[^\$]*` matches word until a `$` is found.

`(?=\s)` checks for presence of white space after word.

**Replacement:** Replace with whatever word you wish to.

**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/x2Vv7I/3/)**

---

**Update:** For the cases like below where words appear at beginning or end.

> $Hello$ The $quick$ brown '$$fox$$' jumps $$over$$ the '$lazy$' dog $Hello$

Use this regex.

**Regex:** `(?:(?<=\s)|(?<=^))([$]{1,2})[^\$]*\1(?=\s|$)`

`(?:(?<=\s)|(?<=^))` looks behind for `whitespace` or `beginning of string.`

`(?=\s|$)` looka ahead for `whitespace` or `end of string.`

**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/x2Vv7I/4/)**

Answer (score 1):

The most common way to skip something is to match and capture it (so as to restore the value later) and just match what you do not need.

See the [C# demo](http://ideone.com/vX8W9q) (`s` stands for *input string*, `p` for *pattern* and `m` for *match*):

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Linq;

public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var s = "The $quick$ brown '$$fox$$' jumps $$over$$ the '$lazy$' dog";
        var p = @"(?x)
                (?<quote>'[^'\\]*(?:\\.[^\\']*)*') # A single quoted string literal pattern
                 |                                 # or
                (?<!\$)              # no $ immediately to the left
                    (\${1,2})        # 1 or 2 $ symbols (Group 1)
                       [^$]+         # 1 or more non-$ chars
                    \1               # Same value as in Group 1 (backreference)
                (?!\$)               # No $ immediately to the left of the current location
              ";            
        var result = Regex.Replace(s, p, m =>
            m.Groups["quote"].Success ? m.Groups["quote"].Value : "substituted");
        Console.WriteLine(result);
        // => The substituted brown '$$fox$$' jumps substituted the '$lazy$' dog
    }
}
```

The regex basically matches either `'...'` substrings placing them into `quote` named group, and then the second part only matches `$...$` or `$$...$$` substrings. `Regex.Replace(s, p, m => m.Groups["quote"].Success ? m.Groups["quote"].Value : "substituted")` checks if `quote` group participated in the match, and if yes, just re-inserts that text to the result. Else, the substitution occurs.